# storing radio button value in sqlite database

Tags: android, radio-button

i have a radio group with two radio buttons in it. I want to get the value of the radio button and then store it in the database..how do i do that?? Pls help! I searched for it but all in vain!
I tried this code but my activity stops working after using it

```
rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1)
    {
        int id=rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton=rg.findViewById(id);
        int radioid=rg.indexOfChild(radioButton);
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(radioid);
        Father_spouse=(String)btn.getText();
    }
```

Comment: Radio button gives you 0 and 1 as out put ..so store as integer them

Comment: @CobraAjgar : he wants to store th text label of radio button instead of a boolean value ( 0 or 1 )

Comment: @Houcine yup i want to store the label..how do i do that??

Comment: @shiv : see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you want to store the text label of your `RadioButton` then use this :

   ```
   // get selected radio button from radioGroup
   int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

   if(selectedId != -1) {    
      // find the radiobutton by returned id
      selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

      // do what you want with radioButtonText (save it to database in your case)
      String radioButtonText = selectedRadioButton.getText();
   }
   ```
2. if you want to save a boolean value so test on the `selectedId` of your `RadioButtons` and save a 0 or 1 to your database column (*Example of two radio buttons to enable/disable updates*) :

   ```
   // get selected radio button from radioGroup
   int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   boolean isAllowUpdate = false;
   switch(selectedId) {
       case R.id.radioAllowUpdate : isAllowUpdate = true; break;
       case R.id.radioDisableUpdate : isAllowUpdate = false; break;
   }

   //save it to database 
   if(isAllowUpdate)
      // true ==> save 1 value
   else 
      // false ==> save 0 value
   ```

**EDIT :**

if you should control the selected value and when send it to database, see this [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton/)

Comment: i tried this code..have a look..`rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
  int selected=rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
  rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selected);
  
  Father_spouse=(String) rb.getText();` it does not store the value i checked..it stores the value that is already checkd wen the activity loads..

Comment: this is normal because you are putting this code in your `onCreate()` method , so  the default selected value will be stored in database, to achieve that, try to add a Button and put your code in `onClick()` method, see my edits

Comment: selectedradiobutton and -1 are two different datatypes..it is showing error

Comment: sorry i've made a simple stupid mistake , the `if` clause should be before , see my edits :)

Comment: does keeping the checked option for radio button in xml file make any difference???

Comment: no ,it is just to tell the app that the X radioButton should be checked by default.