# Saving and retrieving a RadioButton value in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, radio-button, boolean, android-sqlite

In my current project I have a form that stores data in sqlite. I have 3 radio button inside one radio group. what I want to do is save the values of these radio buttons in one fragment and retrieve them in another in case user wanted to edit the form.

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702255/storing-radio-button-value-in-sqlite-database) post but I couldn't solve the problem.

I found out I can't save boolean data in sqlite I should use Integer with 0 and 1 values. But I don't know how to implement it.

In my SQLiteOpenHelper class I made a new column like this:

```
  public static final int COL5 = 0;
```

in my onCreate method i wrote

```
 String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
                "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 + " TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT, " + COL4 + " TEXT, " + COL5 + "  INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";
```

in my add addData method I added it as `Integer`

I don't know how should I save and retrieve it.
How should I save whether or not the radio button is checked as an Integer and then retrieve the same value.

Comment: if radio button is checked then save it as 1 and unchecked save it as 0 when you are retrieving data check the value for COL5, if it is 1 set radioButton.setChecked(true) or set as false .

Answer (score 0):

You have the `RadioButtons` in a `RadioGroup` therefore only one can always be checked. so you need only database entry to store the state. So check which one is `checked` and then store a value between 0 and 4 (or 1 and 5) whatever you like in your database.

so all you need for your table creation is:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
             " radioGroupState INTEGER)";
```

(Note that I dropped the AUTOINCREMENT, because it is unnecessary)
and then query like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            " radioGroupState INTEGER)";

}

public void saveRadioButtonState(Integer state) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("radioGroupState", state);
    getWritableDatabase().update(TABLE_NAME,  cv, ID +"=?", new String[]{ID + ""});
}

public Integer getRadioButtonState() {
    RADIO_GROUP_STATE = "radioGroupState";
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, RADIO_GROUP_STATE, ID + " = ?", new
                    String[]{RADIO_BUTTON_ID.toString()},
            null,
            null, null);
    Integer state = -1;
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        state = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("radioGroupState"));
    }
    c.close();
    return state;
}
```

Addendum: Looking at your previous question I'm a bit confused about what you really want to save in the database. My solution shows you how to save which `RadioButton` was pressed. If you want so save text just replace `Integer` by `String`.